# How to bind data from popup to parent page in angular using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a sample angular app with two data tables in the popup. where I have implements swapping data rows form one table to another.

I have take a save button in the popup page where i need to bind the data table from popup to parent page on clicking save button.

But when I am trying to fetch data in my console from saveToParentPage() function ,I am unable to fetch the data from the second table in my console.

please access my [sample app here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-qjpnfh?file=app%2Ftable.component.ts)

Can anybody help me how can I fetch data from the popup and display the second table from popup in my parent page.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I believe you are printing out the wrong variable.

```
saveToParentPage (){
   console.log(this.checkedDataSource.data);
}
```

In order to pass the data to the parent component, you would need to pass it through the `dialogRef.close` [MatDialogRef](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogRef)

```
saveToParentPage (){
    this.dialogRef.close(this.checkedDataSource.data);
}
```

You would receive it at the parent using the `afterClosed` observable,

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('from the parent component', result);
});
```

Hope this helps.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-data-swap-twvast)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback.... Yes I am able to fetch the data in my console.